# Change search slug in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to edit the search slug in WordPress with this snippet :

```
    function fb_change_search_url_rewrite() {
    if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/search/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
        exit();
    }   
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'fb_change_search_url_rewrite' );
```

And it works great. But i need to change the slug "/search/" to a custom and nothing work except this word. I get a 404 each time i change with others slugs.

Do you have any ideas on how can i achieve this please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a rewrite rule for your custom search slug / permalink

modify your code became like this

```
function fb_change_search_url_rewrite() {
    if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/find/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
        exit();
    }   
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'fb_change_search_url_rewrite' );

//additional rewrite rule + pagination tested
function rewrite_search_slug() {    
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'find(/([^/]+))?(/([^/]+))?(/([^/]+))?/?',
        'index.php?s=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[6]',
         'top'      
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_search_slug' );
```

Tested on local site. Change the word "find" with what you want, and dont forget to **save permalink** after adding this code within your theme function.

Comment: Great ! It works perfectly. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I wrote on function.php:

```
function search_url_rewrite () {
if (is_search() && !empty($_GET['s'])) {
wp_redirect(home_url('/anything/').urlencode(get_query_var('s')));
exit();
}
}
```

add_action('template_redirect','search_url_rewrite');

Try this code..

Comment: Hello, thank you but it doesn't work. I add this to my first code, and after a first try, replace "anything" with my slug right?

Comment: Here is what I wrote on function.php:

function search_url_rewrite () {
if (is_search() && !empty($_GET['s'])) {
wp_redirect(home_url('/anything/').urlencode(get_query_var('s')));
exit();
}
}
add_action('template_redirect','search_url_rewrite');

Comment: Yes, i have the same, but it only work with the slug "search" and i don't know why

Answer (score 0):

we have write script in php and .htaccess formate. please try any on of them..

**php script**

```
function fb_set_search_base() {

    $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite'] -> search_base = 'my_search'; // set new string
}
add_action( 'init', 'fb_set_search_base' );
```

**htaccess script**

```
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} s=(.*)
  RewriteRule ^$ /search/%1? [R,L]
```

For more information.. [see here](http://wpengineer.com/2258/change-the-search-url-of-wordpress/)

Comment: Hello, thank you, i tried you're php code but nothing change in my search slug :-(